# Django - delete button on form not redirecting to the correct path

Tags: django, forms, button

I have a html template on which multiple messages are posted and can be deleted using a 'delete' button that has been created. My code seeks to search for the id of the item to be deleted and delete it, redirecting to /deleteMessage and concatenating with the id number. I don't fully understand the process and have an error I cannot spot.

**html form**

```
<ul>
    {% for g in all_items %}
        <li> {{ g.content }} 
            <form action="/deleteMessage/{{g.id}}/"
            style="display: inline;"
            method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
            </form>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**views.py relevant code**

```
def deleteMessage(request,GuestBookItem_id):
    item_to_delete =GuestBookItem.objects.get(id=GuestBookItem_id)
    item_to_delete.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/worldguestbook/')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('worldguestbook/',worldguestbookView),
    path('login/',loginView),
    path('addMessage/',addMessage),
    path('deleteMessage/',deleteMessage),
    ]
```

I imagine it is this line that is causing the error - an error in concatenation and not redirecting to the right path.

```
**<form action="/deleteMessage/{{g.id}}/"**
```

**Error message:**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/deleteMessage/17/
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
worldguestbook/
login/
addMessage/
deleteMessage/
The current path, deleteMessage/17/, didn't match any of these.
```

**What I tried:**

I tried, in views.py changing this to g.id (instead of GuestBookItems.id) to match with what is in the form, but that didn't work either.

```
item_to_delete =GuestBookItem.objects.get(id=g_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture `GuestBookItem_id` in the URL pattern:

```
path('deleteMessage/<int:GuestBookItem_id>/', deleteMessage),
```

Note that in Python, you would normally use `guest_book_item_id` as the variable name. Or since it's the primary key of a model instance, you could use `pk`. It would be a good idea to use `get_object_or_404`, so that you get a 404 page when the item does not exist.

You're already using a `POST` request, which is a good idea when you are changing or deleting objects. You should also check that it's a POST request in the view.

Finally, it's a good idea to [reverse URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) instead of hardcoding them. First, you need to add names to your URL patterns, then you can use `{% url %}` in the template and `reverse()` or the `redirect` shortcut in the template.

Putting that together, you get:

```
<form action="{% url 'delete_message' g.id %}">

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('worldguestbook/', worldguestbookView, name="worldguestbook"),
    path('login/', loginView, name="login"),
    path('addMessage/', addMessage, name="add_message"),
    path('deleteMessage/', deleteMessage, name="delete_message"),
]

path('deleteMessage/<int:pk>/', deleteMessage),

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect

def deleteMessage(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST"
        item_to_delete = get_object_or_404(GuestBookItem, pk=pk)
        item_to_delete.delete()
    return redirect('worldguestbook')
```

Comment: While you're here and if interested: No one could quite answer this one: stackoverflow.com/questions/55658454/…

Comment: To answer your comment that you deleted - the variable name in the URL pattern and the function signature must match. The variable in the form action is separate.

Comment: So the variable in the form action can be anything...it is simply like a parameter being passed?

Comment: Yes, `/deleteMessage/{{g.id}}/` gets rendered as (say) `/deleteMessage/5/`, and then  the browser submits the form to that URL - it doesn't matter what variable name was used in the template before it was rendered.